# In Google Apps Script, how do you get the Range of the calling cell in a custom function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying to get a reference to the **calling** cell's range in a Google Sheets custom function.

For example:

```
function MyAddress() {
    callingRange = // get calling cell reference here
    return callingRange.getA1Notation();
}
```

`getActiveCell()` isn't guaranteed to work because calculation doesn't necessarily occur while the calling cell is active (I could be wrong about this, but can't find confirmation). Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. (we already have several questions/answer that use `getActiveRange()` but I'm not sure that there are about `getActiveCell()`)